# Problema al añadir numeros a una Base de datos SQL usando PHP

Tags: php, sql

Consigo añadir valores string correctamente, pero cuando añado números, aunque ponga cualquier número, automáticamente la base de datos lo añade como 0. ¿Alguna solución?

```html
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <center>
    <title>Añadir Libro</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <body background="backg.jpg">
    <p style="color:black">Desde aqui podremos <ins>añadir libros
    </ins> a la libreria, especificando todas sus caractericticas.
    </p>
      <?php
      $titulo_libro = null;
      $autor_libro = null;
      $tema_libro = null;
      $paginas_libro = null;
      $tema_libro = null;
      $paginas_libro = null;
      $formatoUno_libro = null;
      $formatoDos_libro = null;
      $formatoTres_libro = null;
      $estado_libro = null;
         if (!($link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")))  
         {  
         echo "Error conectando a la base de datos.";  
         }  
         if (!mysqli_select_db($link, "libreria1617"))
         {
         echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos.";
                  } else if(isset($_POST['titulo_libro'])){
                  $titulo_libro = $_POST['titulo_libro'] ?? '';
                  $autor_libro = $_POST['autor_libro'] ?? '';
                    $tema_libro = $_POST['tema_libro'] ?? '';
                    $paginas_libro = $_POST['numeroPaginas'] ?? '';
                    $formatoUno_libro = $_POST['cartone'] ?? '';
                    $formatoDos_libro = $_POST['rustica'] ?? '';
                       $formatoTres_libro = $_POST['tapadura'] ?? '';
                    $estado_libro = $_POST['estado'] ?? '';

                  $sql=mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `libro` (`Titulo`, `Autor`, `Tema`, `NumPaginas`, `FormatoUno`, `FormatoDos`, `FormatoTres`, `Estado`)
                  VALUES ('$titulo_libro', '$autor_libro', '$tema_libro', '$paginas_libro', '$formatoUno_libro', '$formatoDos_libro', '$formatoTres_libro', '$estado_libro')") 
                  or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
                  if(! $sql ) {
                     die('Error al añadir el libro: ' . mysqli_error($link));
                  }
                  echo "Libro añadido: ".'<br />';
                  mysqli_close($link);
            } else {
            ?>     
               <form method="post" action="annadirlibro.php">
                  <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">


                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Titulo del libro</td>
                        <td><input name = "titulo_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "titulo_libro"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Autor del libro</td>
                        <td><input name = "autor_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "autor_libro"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Tema del libro</td>
                        <td><input name = "tema_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "tema_libro"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Numero de paginas del libro</td>
                        <td><input name = "paginas_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "paginas_libro"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Formato Cartone (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                        <td><input name = "formatoUno_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "formatoUno_libro"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Formato Rustica (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                        <td><input name = "formatoDos_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "formatoDos_libro"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Formato TapaDura (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                        <td><input name = "formatoTres_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "formatoTres_libro"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Estado del libro (0 Normal, 1 Reedicion)</td>
                        <td><input name = "estado_libro" type = "text" 
                           id = "estado_libro"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "button" type = "submit" id = "button" value = "Añadir libro">
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </form>
                <?php } ?>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cual campo te da cero? formatoUno_libro? porque tenes <input name = "formatoUno_libro" pero en el php $_POST['cartone']. deberia ser $_POST['formatoUno_libro']

Comment: Eso era, muchisimas gracias, duda resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta en la consulta:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `libro` (`Titulo`, `Autor`, `Tema`, `NumPaginas`, `FormatoUno`, `FormatoDos`, `FormatoTres`, `Estado`)
       VALUES ('$titulo_libro', '$autor_libro', '$tema_libro', '$paginas_libro', '$formatoUno_libro', '$formatoDos_libro', '$formatoTres_libro', '$estado_libro')")
```

Para el caso de PaginasLibro (que supongo sera un entero) tu sql deberia ser:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `libro` (`Titulo`, `Autor`, `Tema`, `NumPaginas`, `FormatoUno`, `FormatoDos`, `FormatoTres`, `Estado`)
     VALUES ('$titulo_libro', '$autor_libro', '$tema_libro', $paginas_libro, '$formatoUno_libro', '$formatoDos_libro', '$formatoTres_libro', '$estado_libro')")
```

Fíjate que he quitado las comillas alrededor de la variable **$paginas_libro**

Comment: Ooops! Sorry!. No suelo utilizar los botones, lo escribo directamente. Trataré de hacerlo mejor :(

Comment: En ese caso, el código va con 4 espacios al inicio de cada línea

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones una nota en la respuesta advirtiendo al OP sobre la Inyección SQL?

Comment: Pero si hago lo que me dices en todos los valores que son numericos me salta este error...

 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , )' at line 2

Comment: eso es porque las variables donde estan esos parametros estan recibiendo valor NULL.(de hecho las inicializas a ese valor) Ahi ya tendras que jugar tu con las variables y ponerles valor, o preparar la consulta sin ese campo.

Comment: Pero sino las inicio como Null me da un error de Undefined Index...
 Notice: Undefined index: numeroPaginas